# How remove end part of a path (string) using regular expression in MATLAB?

Tags: regex, string, matlab

Suppose that we have these strings in MATLAB:

```
xx = 'C:/MY_folder/This_gg/microsoft/my_file';
```

or

```
xx = 'C:/end_folder/This_mm/google/that_file';
```

I want remove expression after end `/` (`my_file` and `that_file`). How can I do this using regular expression in MATLAB?

Comment: Do you know the name of the file? Otherwise `regexp(xx, '/')` will find the index of all the '/'. Consider using the function `fileparts()` instead.

Comment: @patrik. We don't know name of the file.

Comment: You can use:    
/\/(?!.*?\/)(.*)/g

Comment: `xx = regexprep(xx,'[^/]+$','')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you're asking for a regular expression but there's a simpler way:

```
pathStr = fileparts(xx)
```

Or, if you want all parts of the file

```
[pathStr, name, ext] = fileparts(xx)
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants to keep the final `/`, so consider adding: `pathStr = [pathStr filesep]` (`filesep` resturns the file seperator depending on the operating system

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to **also remove the final `/`**, use

   ```
   yy = regexprep(xx, '/[^/]*$', '');
   ```

   The regexp pattern `'/[^/]*$'` matches a `/` followed by any number of non-`/` at the end of the string. The match is replaced ([`regexprep`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html)) by the empty string.
2. If you want to **keep the final `/`**, you can modify the regexp with a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion:

   ```
   yy = regexprep(xx, '(?<=/)[^/]*$', '');
   ```

   or in 1 replace by `'/'` instead of by `''`:

   ```
   yy = regexprep(xx, '/[^/]*$', '/');
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove last word try this:

```
yy = regexprep(xx,'(\w+)$','');
```

This find last word in the string and replaces it by empty string.

You can see the regex in following link:
[Regex101.com - Select last word](https://regex101.com/r/fD8sB4/1)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regexp you can use fullfile, that is independent if there is '\' or '/'

```
yy = fullfile(xx, '..')
```

This returns the string 'xx\..'.

```
zz = fullfile(yy, 'newfolder')
```

This returns the string 'xx\..\newfolder' but it parses correctly on dir() and other functions.

Of course you can go back and forth in one line.

```
zz = fullfile(xx, '..', 'newfolder')
```